# How to check multiple elements has same class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, class-attributes

Is it possible to minify this selector?

```js
if ($("#element1").hasClass("highlight") && $("#element2").hasClass("highlight") && $("#element3").hasClass("highlight") && $("#element4").hasClass("highlight") && $("#element5").hasClass("highlight")) {
  $("#newstyle).css("visibility", "visible");
};
```

I already tried

```js
if ($("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4, #element5").hasClass("highlight"))
```

and

```js
if ($("#element1 && #element2 && #element3 && #element4 && #element5").hasClass("highlight"))
```

...but that's incorrect.

Basically I have many conditions the same like this: 5 specified elements hasClass `XYZ`. So I'd appreciate it to compress it.

Comment: You've given your elements IDs that fit a pattern, which a couple of the answers are relying on. If they don't actually fit that pattern, probably best to mention that. (I wouldn't change the examples at this point, though; for next time, it would be good **if** that's not how they actually are to try to stick closer to the real situation. If. :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. I should note that I'm assuming the pattern `element1`, `element2`, `element3` isn't really how your IDs are, that you just used that in the question...

I'd probably turn it a bit on its head: Use a group of selectors with `#element:not(.highlight)` and if the result is empty (`length == 0`), they all either have it or don't exist.

```
if (!$("#element1:not(.highlight), #element2:not(.highlight), #element3:not(.highlight), #element4:not(.highlight), #element5:not(.highlight)").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

Example where they all have the class:

```js
if (!$("#element1:not(.highlight), #element2:not(.highlight), #element3:not(.highlight), #element4:not(.highlight), #element5:not(.highlight)").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="newstyle" style="visibility: hidden">I'm visible!</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And where at least one of them doesn't:

Example where they all have the class:

```js
if (!$("#element1:not(.highlight), #element2:not(.highlight), #element3:not(.highlight), #element4:not(.highlight), #element5:not(.highlight)").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="newstyle" style="visibility: hidden">I'm visible!</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If it's all the same class, as in your example, we can be a bit more concise:

```
if (!$("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4, #element5").not(".highlight").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

Example where they all have the class:

```js
if (!$("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4, #element5").not(".highlight").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="newstyle" style="visibility: hidden">I'm visible!</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And where at least one doesn't:

```js
if (!$("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4, #element5").not(".highlight").length) {

  $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="newstyle" style="visibility: hidden">I'm visible!</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've chosen the minified version, when all elements have the same class. (of course my elements are not element1^ ;-) )

Comment: @Sebastian _"of course my elements are not element1^"_ Consider updating original Question to include actual `html` and selectors required, to clarify conditions for future viewers of and prospective Answers to Question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute begins with selector `"[id^=element]"` passed to `Array.prototype.every()`, return `$(el).is(".highlight")` from `.every()` callback

```js
// Note `$("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4, #element5")`
// can be substituted for `$("[id^=element]")` here
if ([].every.call($("[id^=element]"), el => $(el).is(".highlight"))) {
  // do stuff
  console.log("ok");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
```

Alternatively you can check if element which has `.id` beginning with `"element"` and where `.className` contains `"highlight"` followed by whitespace or end of value `.length` is equal to `.length` of elements having `.id` beginning with `"element"`

```js
if ($("[id^=element][class~=highlight]").length === $("[id^=element]").length) {
  console.log("ok")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select all `.highlight` elements, filter based on ID's, and if you have five of those, all the elements with the ID `element1-5` have the class `highlight`, and you can set the style

```
var els = $('.highlight').filter( (_,el)=>/^element[1-5]$/.test(el.id));
if ( els.length===5 ) $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Using a jQuery selector

```
var els = $('[id^=element].highlight').filter('[id$=1],[id$=2],[id$=3],[id$=4],[id$=5]');
if (els.length === 5) $("#newstyle").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all element you want and use jQuery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to replace selected element with class existence of it that is `true/false`. Then use javascript [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check that `false` value exist in array result.

```
var hasClassArr = $("[id^='element']").map(function(){
  return $(this).hasClass("highlight");
}).get();

if (hasClassArr.indexOf(false) == -1)
  console.log("All elements has class");
```

```js
if ($("[id^='element']").map(function(){return $(this).hasClass("highlight");}).get().indexOf(false) == -1)
  console.log("All elements has class");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element2" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element3" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element4" class="highlight"></div>
<div id="element5" class="highlight"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#element1,#element2,#element3,#element4,#element5").filter(".highlight").length == 5){
    $("#newstyle).css("visibility", "visible");
}
```